# How to read a complex json array with SQL Server

Tags: json, sql-server, sql-server-json

This is my query:

```
SELECT
    JSON_QUERY(MyStringColumnWithJson, '$.Images') AS images
FROM MyTable
```

which returns a single field with the JSON data shown here below:

```
"{ 
   "Images":
   [
     {"Name":"test1.jpeg","Description":"originalName1.jpeg"}, 
     {"Name":"test2.jpeg","Description":"originalName2.jpeg"}, 
     {"Name":"test3.jpeg","Description":"originalName3.jpeg"}
   ]
}"
```

How can I read the images result row by row into a temporary table structure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `OPENJSON` which returns a data set, *not* `JSON_VALUE`, which returns a scalar value. For example:

```sql
DECLARE @JSON nvarchar(MAX) = N'{ 
"Images":
   [
     {"Name":"test1.jpeg","Description":"originalName1.jpeg"}, 
     {"Name":"test2.jpeg","Description":"originalName2.jpeg"}, 
     {"Name":"test3.jpeg","Description":"originalName3.jpeg"}
   ]
}';

SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON(@JSON, '$.Images')
     WITH (Name nvarchar(128),
           Description nvarchar(128))OJ;
```

---

```sql
SELECT I.[Name],
       I.Description
FROM MyTable MT
     CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(MT.YourJsonColumn, '$.Images')
                 WITH (Name nvarchar(128),
                       Description nvarchar(128)) I;
```

Comment: this is like all samples I found... they base on a variable containing json... BUT my json is in an sql field! How would you do that?

Comment: Just replace `@JSON` with your column name, @HelloWorld (obviously with the table already referenced in the `FROM`).

Comment: what is OJ at the end?

Comment: An Alias, @HelloWorld ... O for Open, J for JSON. You can use something else if you prefer. For example `I` for `Images`.

Comment: sorry i dont get it...its really confusing. Do i have now 2 select statements? Can you pls use my original code and modify it , thx!

Comment: Done. Like I said, just add the column to `OPENJSON`, @HelloWorld .

Comment: nah... its not only add the column. Without Cross apply nothing makes sense. Anyway thanks!

Comment: So are you saying the above doesn't work, @HelloWorld ..?